# Stdlib support for compile-time metaprogramming?

Tags: elisp, elisp-macros

The following macro...

```
(defmacro compile-time-eval (&rest body)
    (eval (cons 'progn body)))
```

...allows for compile-time metaprogramming like this (a small contrived example) :

```
(compile-time-eval
 `(defun join-dirs (a b)
    (concat a
            ,(if (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
                 "\\"
               "/")
            b)))
```

Is something like `compile-time-eval` part of the standard library? (`eval-when-compile` comes close, but it quotes the result.)

If not, what's the recommended way to implement this example?

Comment: `eval-when-compile` _must_ quote its expansion to avoid re-evaluation at runtime.  Why's that a problem?

Comment: I want the result of the body to be evaluated at runtime. `(eval-and-compile '(defun tmpfn ()))` won't define `tmpfn`.

Comment: Naturally, because you're not actually writing a function definition here.  You're writing a quoted list that just looks like one.  Compare `(eval-and-compile '(defun foo ())` with `(eval-and-compile (defun foo ())`.  Note the absence of the explicit quote.

Comment: Yes, I think I need that level of indirection. How would you implement my example in the style of `(eval-and-compile (defun ...))`?

Comment: See my answer.  Generating function definitions is rather unusual, I'd just call a special macro in the function body.  But generally, I'd avoid macros if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Macros do not evaluate to a result, they evaluate to an *expansion*, which is a form that substitutes the macro at the place where it's written, the *expansion site*. The expansion itself is not evaluated by the compiler.

As such, you normally don't try to generate function definitions completely.  Rather you'd write a macro to performs whatever expansion you'd like to have, and simply use that macro within a function body, i.e.

```
(defmacro my/path-separator ()
  (if (eq system-type 'windows-nt) "\\" "/"))

(defun join-dirs (a b)
  (concat a (my/path-separator) b))
```

But in this specific example, you should not use macros at all.  Emacs' byte code is not actually OS- or architecture-specific, and thus you must not generate system-specific code during expansion.  In other words, the path separator is not a compile time constant, it's a load time constant and should be computed at load time rather than at compile time.

Generally you should only use macros for *syntax*, but **never** for semantics.

And actually you'd just use `(expand-file-name "b" "a")` here :)

Comment: Thanks. Actually, *all* I care about is semantics – I want to shift some run-time computations to compile-time. What else should I use other than macros?

Comment: @ens Just don't do that at all…. It's of no use and has no benefits.

Comment: The first line is a bit ambiguous (right or wrong, depending on the reading). When *evaluated*, a sexp that is a list whose car is a macro is first *expanded*, and then the result of expansion is *evaluated*. Macro expansion (function `macroexpand`) just expands.

Comment: @Drew I've tried to clarify it. Better now?

Comment: Very good - that will help readers more, I think.